Write a dynamic reference to a list item in a numbered list
when drafting a document with clauses in google drive, we set out the document like this

some clause
some clause
some clause

As we are drafting the document we may need to write a reference to a clause such as "with reference to clause 2 above".
If we are to add in a new clause between 1 and 2, the new clause becomes clause 2 and the old clause 2 becomes 3 and so on.
The problem is when we write "with reference to clause 2 above" the reference to the clause in that text dosnt update as its just static text.
Is there anyway to get the reference to a clause written as "with reference to clause 2 above" to be dynamic ?
